# Relay Alternative

Tags: relay, alternatives

I wanted to see if I had any alternative to a relay for my project.

I'm turning on a heating element that is powered from the wall: 120VAC (Max 30 Amps)

Is their any alternative to a relay for this project? The contacts seem to be taking a beating over the course time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solid state relay would be a good fit.  Search one of the distributors for your specs (current, voltage, & control voltage).

For example check out this datasheet: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/93/s_1_120-368679.pdf

Comment: Thanks I think your right, solid state is a great alternative!

Comment: Cool, hth.  And, the silence!